# Loop through folder and merge files?

Tags: batch-file

I want to loop through a folder that contains text files and marge them together.

When they are merger i want to remove duplicates and sort them.

How would i accomplish this with a batch script?

Comment: Merge? Or do you mean concatenate? if file1.txt and file2.txt need to be 'merged' how will the 'merged' file be named? How do you want the files to be sorted?

Comment: I want to grab all .txt files in a folder i specify and merge them into 1 file for ex. take file1.txt file2.txt and file3.txt and combine them into new_file.txt

Answer (score 2):

As long as the target filename doesn't match the wildcard spec, the easiest way to do this is like this:

```
copy /b file?.txt new_file.txt
```

The `/b` means copy in "binary" mode. Otherwise the default is `/a` which will stop copying any source file at a `Ctrl+Z`, and will append a `Ctrl+Z` at the end of the file.

If, as the comment below indicates, there is some fear that one or more files may not end properly with a CRLF, then an alternate solution is

```
(for %i in (file?.txt) do type %i)>new_file.txt
```

If the filenames have spaces or other odd characters, you might need to quote them, like this:

```
(for %i in (*.txt) do type "%i")>new_file.txt
```

But that is only part of the answer. To remove unique names, there are several solutions which use only batch files, or which use powershell, but the simplest would really be to grab the GnuWin32 sort utility. It can be gotten from [SourceForge](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm). Then the answer becomes simply:

```
(for %i in (*.txt) do type "%i")|sort -u|>new_file.txt
```

The side benefit of this is that the GNU sort is an extremely useful utility.

Comment: +1; Based on some quick tests, it appears you don't have to worry about the wildcard spec matching the target name. As long as the target file is a brand new file name, then all works well.

Comment: But this will not work properly if the last line of a file does not end  with a linefeed. The last line will get merged with the 1st line of the next file.

Answer (score 1):

Complementing lavinio answer, to honor OP requirement "remove duplicates and sort them", 
after concatenating the files, use powershell sort and get-unique commands

```
gc allfiles.txt | sort | get-unique > allfiles.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Lavinio's solution will not work properly if the last line in some files is not terminated by a line feed.

Here is a simple command (no batch needed) that will safely concatenate all the files even if last lines not terminated by line feed. Double up the percents if run from within a batch file.

```
>merged.tmp (for %F in (*.txt) do type "%F")
```

If you want to sort and remove duplicate lines then PA has a powershell solution. Here is a batch solution that sorts and removes duplicate lines. Note that SORT is case insensitive in batch, so the duplicate removal is also case insensitive.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
>merged.tmp (for %%F in (*.txt) do type "%%F")
sort /rec 8192 merged.tmp /o merged.tmp2
>merged.txt (
  for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%A in (merged.tmp2) do (
    set "newLn=%%A"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    if /i "!newLn!" neq "!ln!" (
      endlocal
      set "ln=%%A"
      echo %%A
    ) else endlocal
  )
)
del merged.tmp merged.tmp2
```

Comment: @PA - Actually the wild card was intentional so that both merged.tmp and merged.tmp2 were deleted. But I realize now I should delete both explicitly. I fixed your fix :-)

Comment: EDIT - Added `SORT /REC` option to handle largest line size supported by batch, and added `/O` option for alleged improved performance.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your cmd file:

```
set cpy=
set filter=*.txt
set target=new_file.txt
del newfile.tmp
rem buildup concat
for %%a in (%filter%) do call :concat "%%a"

ren newfile.tmp %target%

rem REMOVE FILES! (carefull please!)
for %%a in (%filter%) do del /Q "%%a"
goto :done

:concat
if EXIST newfile.tmp ( copy newfile.tmp+%1 newfile.tmp ) else ( copy %1 newfile.tmp)
goto :EOF

:done
echo ready
```

Comment: This removes all files and does not create the new_file.txt